# Deleting unpushed duplicate git commits due to erroneus rebase for date change?

Tags: git

I had been trying to modify a timestamp of unpushed commit, and made a mistake (did a new branch and merge, instead of a rebase --continue) which resulted with duplicates of the commits not yet pushed. Here is a bash script that simulates the issue, say `test.sh`:

```bash
rm -rf mytestgit
mkdir mytestgit
cd mytestgit
git init
git config user.email "you@example.com"
git config user.name "Your Name"

SLEEPTIME=5

git commit --allow-empty -m 'first commit'
echo " (... wait ...) "; sleep $SLEEPTIME
git commit --allow-empty -m 'second commit'
echo " (... wait ...) "; sleep $SLEEPTIME
THIRDC=$(git commit --allow-empty -m 'third commit')
echo $THIRDC
echo " (... wait ...) "; sleep $SLEEPTIME
git commit --allow-empty -m 'fourth commit'

git status

git --no-pager log --graph --abbrev-commit --all --decorate --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s %d" ; echo # add '\n' at end
GLOGLAST=$(git --no-pager log -1 --graph --abbrev-commit --all --decorate --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s %d")
IFS=+ read left SPLITGLLA <<< "$GLOGLAST"
IFS="   " read SPLITGLL right  <<< "$SPLITGLLA" # this is TAB here, not space, for IFS
TIMEZONE=${SPLITGLL[0]}
SPLITTC=(${THIRDC//]/ })
THIRDCHASH="${SPLITTC[1]}"
THIRDCUTS=$(git show -s --format=%ct $THIRDCHASH)
THIRDCUTSNEW=$((THIRDCUTS-3))
echo "Third commit hash: $THIRDCHASH, Unix timestamp $THIRDCUTS, timezone +$TIMEZONE, new Unix timestamp (three seconds earlier) $THIRDCUTSNEW"
echo

# cd mytestgit # already in
# here choose $THIRDCHASH with e, saving and closing text editor
git rebase $THIRDCHASH^ -i --keep-empty
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$THIRDCUTSNEW +$TIMEZONE" git commit --amend --no-edit --allow-empty --date "$THIRDCUTSNEW +$TIMEZONE"

# here the mistake
git checkout -b newbranch
git checkout master
git merge newbranch
git branch -d newbranch

# check final state
git --no-pager log --graph --abbrev-commit --all --decorate --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s %d" ; echo # add '\n' at end
```

When I run this script, I get, say this output:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/mytestgit/.git/
[master (root-commit) 1a5fa9a] first commit
 (... wait ...) 
[master f6b51cc] second commit
 (... wait ...) 
[master f9871cc] third commit
 (... wait ...) 
[master cfd0208] fourth commit
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
* cfd0208   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:05:00 2018 +0200   fourth commit  (HEAD, master)
* f9871cc   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:55 2018 +0200   third commit 
* f6b51cc   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:50 2018 +0200   second commit 
* 1a5fa9a   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:45 2018 +0200   first commit 
Third commit hash: f9871cc, Unix timestamp 1538478295, timezone +0200, new Unix timestamp (three seconds earlier) 1538478292

Stopped at f9871cca92f2e3da587fa8b16021f8e52976c8d9... third commit
You can amend the commit now, with

    git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

    git rebase --continue
```

... then at the rebase, I have this in the auto-started text editor (having changed the first `pick` into `e`):

```
e f9871cc third commit
pick cfd0208 fourth commit

# Rebase f6b51cc..cfd0208 onto f6b51cc
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

... which I save, then exit the text editor - the script continues with:

```
[detached HEAD 63e35fe] third commit
Switched to a new branch 'newbranch'
Switched to branch 'master'
```

... and at the erroneous merge, I get this in the auto-started text editor:

```
Merge branch 'newbranch'

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

... which I save without changes, then exit the text editor - and the script concludes with showing the final state:

```
Already up-to-date!
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
Deleted branch newbranch (was 63e35fe).
*   9b1ac28 Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:05:36 2018 +0200   Merge branch 'newbranch'  (HEAD, master)
|\  
| * 63e35fe Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:52 2018 +0200   third commit 
* | cfd0208 Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:05:00 2018 +0200   fourth commit 
* | f9871cc Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:55 2018 +0200   third commit 
|/  
* f6b51cc   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:50 2018 +0200   second commit 
* 1a5fa9a   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:45 2018 +0200   first commit
```

So, now I have duplicate commits (63e35fe "third commit"), as well as a merge commit (9b1ac28 "Merge branch 'newbranch'") instead of a duplicate "fourth commit".

Basically, I have second and first commit pushed already to online repo, but third and fourth haven't been pushed yet.

How can I delete the duplicate (63e35fe "third commit", which is the one that ended up with the changed timestamp, instead of the original f9871cc "third commit") and extra merge (9b1ac28 "Merge branch 'newbranch'") commits so I don't end up pushing them to the repo?

Or in other words, how can I restore the state of the repo to before the `git rebase $THIRDCHASH^ -i --keep-empty` command ran - so I can re-run it again, and properly conclude it with `git rebase --continue` instead of merge, so I can push the "original" commits (and not the duplicates/extras) online?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, at the state at end of OP, there is still a rebase-merge directory:

```
$ git rebase f6b51cc^ -i --keep-empty

It seems that there is already a rebase-merge directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
    git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
    rm -fr "/tmp/mytestgit/.git/rebase-merge"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.
```

... and an additional step I've done and I've forgotten to mention is to do:

```
rm -fr "/tmp/mytestgit/.git/rebase-merge"
```

... which then results with following graph:

```
$ git --no-pager log --graph --abbrev-commit --all --decorate --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s %d" ; echo
* 93bf274   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:05:00 2018 +0200   fourth commit  (HEAD, master)
*   9b1ac28 Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:05:36 2018 +0200   Merge branch 'newbranch' 
|\  
| * 63e35fe Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:52 2018 +0200   third commit 
* | cfd0208 Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:05:00 2018 +0200   fourth commit 
* | f9871cc Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:55 2018 +0200   third commit 
|/  
* f6b51cc   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:50 2018 +0200   second commit 
* 1a5fa9a   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:45 2018 +0200   first commit
```

Then, I did `git rebase f6b51cc^ -i --keep-empty` with:

```
pick f6b51cc second commit
pick f9871cc third commit
pick cfd0208 fourth commit
#pick 63e35fe third commit
#pick 93bf274 fourth commit

# Rebase 1a5fa9a..93bf274 onto 1a5fa9a
#
# Commands:
...
```

... so that 63e35fe and 93bf274 are removed (note that 9b1ac28 "Merge branch 'newbranch'" is not in the given list), I get as a result:

```
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

... and the state here is:

```
$ git --no-pager log --graph --abbrev-commit --all --decorate --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s %d" ; echo
* cfd0208   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:05:00 2018 +0200   fourth commit  (HEAD, master)
* f9871cc   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:55 2018 +0200   third commit 
* f6b51cc   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:50 2018 +0200   second commit 
* 1a5fa9a   Your Name   Tue Oct 2 13:04:45 2018 +0200   first commit
```

... which is the state from before the first rebase (that should have changed the timestamp) - and that is what I wanted.